# How can I have more than one extra row for a multi value field when generating a form?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form with a field that is allowed multiple values(infinite).
Drupal allows one extra empty value to be added between each save but I want to increase this to n number of extra empty values.

I tried in a hook_form_alter adding extra empty value to the field array but only the first one will save as with Drupals default behavior.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to have more empty values available and if so how?
I can not save the form between generating them one by one though.

Comment: You ought to be able to do this in the form alter. Try `$form_state['field']['field_my_field_name']['und']['items_count'] += 2;`

Comment: Scratch my comment above – this would happen after the widget is already built. If I was needing to do this, I'd implement a custom widget and add it there. It's a little more work than you're probably wanting to do, but if you're interested I can post more code in an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Charlie. I was hoping to not have to do too much, but at the same time I would definitely be interested in seeing this code  you speak of.

Comment: You mention only the first one saves – do you mean that you alter the form, view it, it shows 2 blank fields, enter data in both, and the 2nd set of data is not saved? If so, can you post your code?